# Can you scroll the window in interactive substitute mode?

Tags: substitute, scrolling

I am using an interactive substitution that spans multiple lines. In order to determine whether each particular occurrence should be replaced, I need to see all lines that are included in the search criteria, but vim only displays the first line.

I know you can scroll the window with `zz`, `zt` and `zb`, but this doesn't appear to work in interactive substitute mode. Is there an alternative approach?

Here is an example command, which replaces three newlines with two:

```
:1,$s/\n\n\n/^M^M/gce
```

Comment: First run `/\n\n\n` and then do `:%s//\r\r/gce`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question (and if I read [the documentation on the [c] flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s_flags) properly), I would have known that using `CTRL-E` and `CTRL-Y` scroll the screen up and down, respectively.

> [c] Confirm each substitution.  Vim highlights the matching string with...
>
> CTRL-E  to scroll the screen up {not in Vi, not available when compiled without the |+insert_expand| feature}
>
> CTRL-Y  to scroll the screen down {not in Vi, not available when compiled without the |+insert_expand| feature}